# Bind Linq Result to datagridview

Tags: c#, linq

i have a linq result as var & query as following

```
     var groups = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("X"))
              .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key,Count=g.Count() });
```

I want to bind the result to datagridview.

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you having as a problem?

Comment: What did you try? What is the error message?

Comment: Not able to bind the groups result to a datagridview, I have tried the datagridview.DataSource = group; but it is not working!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = groups.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

**updated**

Have you tried this way?

```
yourGridView.DataSource=groups.ToList();
yourGridView.DataBind();
```

for WinForm apps only do this:

```
yourGridView.DataSource=groups.ToList();
```

Comment: The OP is asking about `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` which has no `DataBind` method.

Comment: Ok you don't need to call DataBind method for winform application it's only nedeed for ASP.NET apps!

Comment: Sorry dear, but there is no `DataBind` method at all in `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`. It is a different control than `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView`. It is not a matter of application type !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var groups = (myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("X"))
                  .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key,Count=g.Count() })).ToList();
gridview1.DataSource=groups;
```