# how to convert list object to list string( getting error Unable to cast object of type)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hi Friends i have a list of objects `private static List<Transaction> transactions;`

i am querying through the list to filter the data with some criteria. but i am not able to return the list string. i am getting the error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   <>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]
>   to type 'System.String'.

my plan is to make the datagridview source this list like `dataGridView2.DataSource = BasicClass.banksearch("ABC");`

```
public static List<string> banksearch(string bankname, string sdate = null, string edate = null, string condition = null)
    {
        List<string> returnstr = new List<string>();
        if (sdate == null && edate == null)//only bank
        {
            returnstr = transactions
                .Where(t => t.BankName == bankname)
                .Select(t => new
                 {
                     TransactionID = t.TransactionID,
                     BankName = t.BankName,
                     TemplateModel = t.TemplateModel,
                     Date = t.Date.ToString(),
                     PayeeName = t.PayeeName,
                     Amount = t.Amount.ToString()
                 }).Cast<String>().ToList();
        }
       return returnstr;
       }
```

my class file is

```
class Transaction
{
        public int TransactionID { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string TemplateModel { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string PayeeName { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }        
}
```

Please give me idea to get the result

Comment: You're creating an anonymous object. Why do you expect it to be convertible to a `string`? I think you may really want to return a `List<Transaction>`

Comment: when i do like this i get error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#3>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<chequenew.Transaction>'

Comment: @JineshSam what do you need to be in these strings you return?

Comment: Why not just `return transactions.Select(t => t.BankName == bankname).ToList();` ?

Comment: @takemyoxygen i am getting this error 
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: i requirement is to fill the datagridview

Comment: DataGridView is a separate question imho. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6174802/397817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert to a string in order to use this result as a datasource (although if you actually need a string I can show you how to create a formatted string instead of an anonymous class object). You likely need something like this:

```
public static List<Transaction> banksearch(string bankname, string sdate = null, string edate = null, string condition = null)
    {
        if (sdate == null && edate == null)//only bank
        {
           return transactions // type: List<Transaction>
                .Where(t => t.BankName == bankname)
                .ToList();
        } else {
           return new List<Transaction>();
       }
  }
```

Comment: There's no need to project a new `Transaction` for each object. `transcations` is already a `List<Transaction>`.

Comment: I'm not. That's the else block effectively.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand your comment. what `else` block?

Comment: Inside the if, I return query.ToList(). Method execution ends at that point. Callers which didn't hit the if will hit return new List<Transaction>();. I've made this explicit now by adding an else block.

Comment: Im not talking about that. Your LINQ query generated a `new Transcation` for each transaction object. It's unnecessary as the source collection is already a `List<Transaction>`. See my answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought the query was on a database. Noted, thanks.

Comment: Now our answers are exactly the same :)

Comment: Certainly will be if you take my suggestion about not instantiating a list twice :) The only difference is I took longer getting there!

Comment: @StephenKennedy Thanks its work now.
why Yuval Itzchakov soultion does not fill datagridview that also returing list transaction object

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to project the entire collection onto an `Anonymous Object`.
All you're actually doing is filtering by `bankname`:

```
public static List<Transaction> BankSearch(string bankname, string sdate = null, string edate = null, string condition = null)
{
    List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = new List<Transaction>();
    if (sdate == null && edate == null)
    {
        filteredTransactions = transactions.Where(t => t.BankName == bankname).ToList();
    }

    return filteredTransactions;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create new List<Transaction>() when your query is calling ToList(). For callers which enter the if block, you are creating a list twice.

Comment: `Enumerable.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<Transaction>`, not a `List<Transaction>`. That's why i call `ToList`.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Now no error but no items to display in the datagridview

Comment: @JineshSam That may be because your `DataGridView` doesn't know how to represent a custom object.

Comment: You can do 'return *query*.ToList()' inside your if block and 'else return new List<Transaction>()', to avoid the instantiation.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I understand, but i think that isn't the point of the question.